# Smallest n bit Binary Number Creation in Java

Tags: java, binary, bit-manipulation

How can we create a smallest binary number whose length is given.

For example, 
            the smallest binary number of length 4 is 1000

```
         the smallest binary number of length 3 is 100.
```

I am not able to come up with any algorithm since length is only given.
         This process of creating the number is to be done 
         numerous time with varying length.
What can be the code for that?

Comment: Since your answer is always a 1 followed by (length - 1) 0s, the algorithm seems blindingly obvious...

Comment: Hint: Use the `<<` bit-shift operator.

Comment: @azurefrog so how will you write the code for creating this number since this process needs to be done numerous time with different length

Comment: @torrtuga Java has syntax which allows you to execute a block of code a set number of times.  See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html). If you put this 'loop' into a method, and pass the length in as a parameter to that method...

Comment: @azurefrog i don't know how can a binary number be created of varying length. If i have only one number I can initialize as 100 or 1000 whatever the length is given. So can we use Math.pow(10,length) to create the required binary number

Comment: Well, 100 and 1000 are decimal integers, in Java if you want to have a binary number as a [primitive type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), you need to prefix the numbers with a `0b`, so `0b100` is `4`, and `0b1000` is 8, etc.  Furthermore, the fact that you're suggesting that you can come up with a binary number by multiplying by 10 a bunch of times suggests to me that you don't really understand what a binary number *is*...

Comment: Lastly, what have you tried so far?  SO is not a code-writing service.  People here volunteer their time to help **you** fix **your** code.  Post your existing program, what the inputs are, what you think it should output, what it actually outputs, etc.  See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this](http://sscce.org/) for advice on how to ask better questions.

Answer (score -2):

That is easy: 0, 00, 000, 0000, 00000, ....

On the serious note, binary is just another notation. What you have is a simple computation like this

```
binary 1 = decimal 1
binary 10 = decimal 2
binary 100 = decimal 4
binary 1000 = decimal 8
```

So you can do

```
int myNumber = 1;
for (int i = 1; i < LENGTH; i++)
    myNumber = myNumber * 2;
```

Or use

```
myNumber = Math.pow(2, LENGTH - 1);
```

Comment: @filip how can I initialize a binary number as 100 or 1000 or 100000 as per the length requirement. What should be the code?